# I am looking for a script (php prefably) to give me all the links of a website

Tags: php

I have come across lots of code which will find all the links on a page.  I would like something that takes it a step further and finds it for the whole site.

Spidering the links is a little trickier than in seems!

Any ideas will be greatly received.

Comment: *(related)* http://superuser.com/questions/47089/wget-download-list-of-files-on-file-server

Answer (score 2):

Just feed the links you find on the pages back into the function that gets the links for one page. Keeping track of which pages you have done and making sure you don't jump out to another domain.